# How to keep a Chronometer running in the background?

Tags: android, chronometer

I have in a `Activity` (1) A `Chronometer` and is running fine. I click a `Button` and starts `Chronometer` time count.

I'm trying to keep the score `Chronometer` changing `Activity` (2) but without success.

In this new `Activity` (2) does not have the layout `Chronometer` one component.
I tried to pass the `Chronometer` object of `Activity` (1) to the other `Activity` (2) and continue the count but continues even taking this Chronometer and giving a new `start()` does not count the time.
I tried to pass the component `Chronometer` via `Intent.putExtra()` and creating a memory class.

I tried to even create the `Activity` (2) a `Chronometer` in invisible layout and pass only the value of `Chronometer.getBase()` and give a `start()`, is not counting the time.
In `Activity` (2) should continue recording the time and return to the `Activity` (1) `Chronometer` should be visible elapsed time.

The `Activity` (1) and (2) die with the `finish()`.

Comment: Use Fragments instead of activities :)

Comment: If I have to use Activity by "force majeure".

Comment: Ok maybe making your chronometer static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply! I had tried before this medium but without success. In fact I analyzed my code better and saw that I was sabotaging myself. A new instance of Chronometer was created after setting it to start counting. So it does not accounted for. and taking advantage would have to use their means of more this code timing:

```
long restartTime = getIntent().getLongExtra(Constantes.TIME, 0) + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

This was when set the current getBase the Chronometer in question the previous Activity.

And step for the Activity to be called the following putExtra():

```
long valueChrono = chronometer.getBase()
                    - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Thank you and sorry for any problems!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep a reference to the original start time. See the [Chronometer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) for more details, but the gist is:

```
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
chronometerInstance.setBase(startTime);
chronometerInstance.start();
```

Then you can pass `startTime` around to other activities and continue to use that same value anytime you need to start a chronometer.