# Don't stop chronometer while using another app

Tags: android, background, chronometer

For example: in the App I have a Chronometer, I click on play to start it and when it arrives at 00:00:10 I receive a call. I stay talking for 30 seconds before returning to mi app. I would find the timer paused still displaying 00:00:10, but I'd like to see it still running and then at 00:00:40. How can I do this? How can I avoid the timer pausing on the change of App?.

Im using the native tool Chronometer of Android Studio
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Thanks

Comment: Implement `Chronometer` in `Service` like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35622084/6950238) question of [praj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1966126/praj)

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442912/how-to-keep-a-chronometer-running-in-the-background) is other ways to  keep `Chronometer` counting in background.

Comment: I know this question is old but I would just like to add that 'Chronometer' will stop/reset when app is destroyed.